# Jquery Mobile listview undefined and listview refresh not working on data-rel back

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, listview

I am working on my first JQM application which is an imaginary accommodation app for my university project and I am really struggling to understand how to work with page events.

I have a page main.html which has options to search for properties, the different search options will have query string,

On the toPage which is results.html the results will be displayed,

Listview refresh works, but this is the main problem:
a) when I go to the results page I see undefined printed on top of the screen
b) When I go back to main.html from results.html, I see the same results of the results page being shown on the bottom of the main.html page, its like some bug has left them at the bottom half cut off 
These results disappear after only after I refresh main.html,

I hope i made sense, my code is below, any advice would be appreciated thanks

main.html:

```
                <div data-role="collapsibleset" data-inset="false">
                    <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false" data-collapsed-icon="false" data-expanded-icon="false">
                        <h5>Search by Area</h5>
                        <ul data-role="listview" data-icon="false">
                            <li><a href="results.html?id=od&ref=area">Orange Dessert</a></li>
                            <li><a href="results.html?id=sd&ref=area">Snow Dune</a></li>
                            <li><a href="results.html?id=yhv&ref=area">Yellow Hut Village</a></li>
                            <li><a href="results.html?id=rb&ref=area">Red Beach</a></li>
                            <li><a href="results.html?id=ic&ref=area">Inner City</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false" data-collapsed-icon="false" data-expanded-icon="false">
                        <h5>Search by Price</h5>
                        <ul data-role="listview" data-icon="false">
                            <li><a href="results.html?id=pr1&ref=price">$0 and $499</a></li>
                            <li><a href="results.html?id=pr2&ref=price">$500 and $999</a></li>
                            <li><a href="results.html?id=pr3&ref=price">$1000 and $1499</a></li>
                            <li><a href="results.html?id=pr4&ref=price">$1500 and 1999</a></li>
                            <li><a href="results.html?id=pr5&ref=price">$2000 and $3000</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false" data-collapsed-icon="false" data-expanded-icon="false">
                        <h5>Distance from UOZ</h5>
                        <ul data-role="listview" data-icon="false">
                            <li><a href="results.html?id=dist1&ref=dist">Less than 5 miles</a></li>
                            <li><a href="results.html?id=dist2&ref=dist">5 and 9 miles</a></li>
                            <li><a href="results.html?id=dist3&ref=dist">10 and 14 miles</a></li>
                            <li><a href="results.html?id=dist4&ref=dist">15 and 19 miles</a></li>
                            <li><a href="results.html?id=dist5&ref=dist">More than 20 miles</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

        <a href="results.html?id=all" data-role="button">Search All</a>
```

script2.js:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#resPg", function () {

$(document).on("pagecontainerbeforeshow", function (e, ui) {
    var page = ui.toPage[0].id;

    if (page == 'resPg') {
        $.getJSON("json/huts.json", function(data){
            var place;
            $(data.huts).each(function (index, value) {
                place += "<li>" + value.title + "</li>";
            })

            $("ul").html(place);

            $("ul").listview().listview("refresh");
        })
    }
})
```

})

results.html

```
 <div data-role="main">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-icon="false">

        </ul>
    </div>
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Very important to give  an id on results page. To Page and From page both have unordered lists so it was important to distinguish, during AJAX transition, the data from the toPage was going back to the fromPage.

Its sorted by either giving an id to the unordered list like this

```
</ul>
```

Or by calling the pagecontainerhide event
    $(document).on("pagecontainerbeforeshow", function (e, ui) {

```
var page = ui.toPage[0].id;

if (page == 'resPg') {
    $.getJSON("json/huts.json", function(data){
        var place;
        $(data.huts).each(function (index, value) {
            place += "<li>" + value.title + "</li>";
        })

        $("#result_lw").html(place);

        $("#result_lw").listview().listview("refresh");

    })
}

$(document).on("pagecontainerhide", function () {
    $("ul").html("");
})
```

})